# Could not read document: Expected type float, integer, or string

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to send put request and i receive the following error,

```
    Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Expected type float, integer, or string.
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Expected type float, integer, or string.
```

Value in entity: (converter is of type: AttributeConverter, tried to remove it still doesn't work)

```
@Convert(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @Column(name = "LAST_MODIFIED")
    protected ZonedDateTime lastModified;
```

Merge:

```
this.entityManager.merge(entity);
        this.entityManager.flush();
```

Using:

```
jackson-datatype-jsr310
```

I tried to use JsonSerializer and JsonDeSerializer but the result is the same.

Converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(final ZonedDateTime attribute) {
        if(attribute == null){
            return null;
        }
        return Date.from(attribute.toInstant());
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final Date dbData) {
        if(dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(dbData.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity update(@RequestBody final DTO dto) {
        boolean updated = this.service.update(dto);
        if(updated){
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

Comment: `ZonedDateTimeConverter` : is it your own class (please show the code) or does it come from a third-party library?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Added it.

Comment: The problem is in the rest controller. Can you show it ?

Comment: @MichaelJapeson imho, your input type cannot be a date (it is not a valid JSON type). It should be a string representing a date. Hence, your converter should implement `AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, String>`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The converter is for the database not for json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i put JsonSerializer and JsonDeSerializer on entity not on the DTO after changing